# How to convert ViewBox svg to zero initial coordinates?

Tags: javascript, math, svg, coordinates

I have the following svg with viewBox:

```
viewBox="16.350 -671.025 1150.675 852.600"

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="16.350 -671.025 1150.675 852.600" width="1150.675px" height="852.600px">
<circle cx="1006.275" cy="-420.45" r="5" fill="#000" class="pointer" id="controurcircle_1"></circle>
</svg>
```

As you can see `viewBox` contains initial users coordinates. If I change it to `0,0` as standard, how coordinates of circle should be changes?

```
let circleX = Math.abs(Math.abs(1006.275) + Math.abs(16.350));
let circleY = Math.abs(Math.abs(-420.45) - Math.abs(-671.025));
```

Right?

Comment: First of all you should explain clearly why it is important to you to keep that svg instead of creating a new where viewBox x and y values are 0?
You say this viewBox contains initial users coordinates. What do you mean by that? I'm working with svgs since the first day and never have seen any svg with such a viewBox values. Anyway your svg is a tiny black circle displayed in some extrange location of the screen when I open it in the browser. Which is the role you are using it for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have all the `abs()` calls in there.

You will need to subtract the viewBox minX and minY fields from all your (absolute) coordinates.  Don't alter any relative coordinate pairs (lower case path commands) in any `<path>` elements you might have.

```
viewBox="0 0 1150.675 852.600"

let circleX = 1006.275 - 16.350;
let circleY = -420.45 - (-671.025);  // = -420.45 + 671.025
```